# (bash script) error running g-wan

Tags: bash, path, g-wan

Every time I try to run g-wan I get the following error:

```
./gwan: 1:Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

I have tried both 32 and 64 bit versions.

I am running it in ubuntu 11 and I have installed all the necessary packages, any idea what is going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're not running G-WAN (a compiled program): you are rather a system script (the error is a system bash scripting error not a C runtime error).

Make sure that you are in the G-WAN program directory when you run `./gwan`